# Jersey server: Return a string and a non-200 return code

Tags: java, jersey

I have the following method:

```
@GET
@Path("/myFunc")
public String myFunc(@QueryParam("input") String input) {
    if (! input.startsWith("123")) {
        return "Usage error: input must start with '123'";
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

The problem is that logically, when I return the string `"Usage error: input must start with '123'"`, the return code is 200. How can I change that, so that I can return the string, while changing the return code, say, to 400?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` type for such cases - sth along these lines:

```
@GET
@Path("/myFunc")
public Response myFunc(@QueryParam("input") String input) {
    if (! input.startsWith("123")) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                       .entity("Usage error: input must start with '123'")
                       .build();
    }
    return Response.ok("Success").build();
}
```

Comment: I added `.build()` in the last line of your code. Your response was to the point and perfect (and very very helpful!), thank you!